# Accessing parent Makefile targets from subdirectory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say my directory structure is this:

```
foo
foo/Makefile
foo/bar
```

Now say `foo/Makefile` has a make target `baz`.

I want to call `make baz` from `foo/bar` without creating another Makefile in the `bar` subdirectory. Is this possible?

Comment: `make -f ../Makefile baz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU `make` has two important options for your situation: `-f FILE` is used to tell `make` which makefile(s) to use instead of the defaults and `-C DIR` tells `make` to change to directory `DIR` before reading the makefiles. How to use one or the other or both depends on your specific case. Note that `-f` is compliant with the POSIX standard while `-C` is an extension supported by GNU `make`. If `-C` is not supported by your own version of `make` and has no equivalent you will have to change the current directory yourself before invoking `make`, e.g. `( cd some/where; make...; )`.

1. If you can build `baz` from `foo/bar/`, as suggested by [Oo.oO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5295429/oo-oo), you can simply

   ```
    make -f ../Makefile baz
   ```

   `make` will run from `foo/bar/` and build `baz` as indicated in `../Makefile`.
2. If you must be in `foo/` to build `baz` you should use:

   ```
    make -C .. baz
   ```

   `make` will change to `..`, that is, `foo` before reading the makefiles and as it will find here one of the defaults (`Makefile`) it will use it to discover how to build `baz`.
3. If you must be in another directory, e.g. the parent of `foo/`, you need both options and type:

   ```
    make -C ../.. -f foo/Makefile baz
   ```

   `make` will first change to `../..` (parent directory of `foo/`) and from here it will use `foo/Makefile` to discover how to build `baz`.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Is there a way to do this without adding new flags? Say I am working on a complex directory structure, it is not feasible to create a new Makefile for each directory. I’m considering the best way to do this is via a bash script.

Comment: You should probably try to explain a bit better what you would like to do and, more important, what are your constraints. I do not really understand why using `make` options is a problem.

Comment: My question is, if there is no Makefile in a directory, how can you make it default to the Makefile in the parent directory without adding options. Is this something that is possible?

Comment: @ChukwudiDerekUche: Well, you could download the make sources, modify them such that it also searches the default makefiles in the parent directory, and recompile. You could also create symbolic links. You could also define a shell function or alias to wrap make inside a simple script that does all this for you. Example if your makefiles are always named `Makefile`: `function my_make { if [ ! -f Makefile ] && [ -f ../Makefile ]; then make -f ../Makefile $*; else make $*; fi }`. But there are some side effects that you should probably consider (`$(MAKE)`, etc.)